Gradient output through custom loss function
I’m very new to Pytorch (and ML in general), so I’m having difficulty understanding what is going on WRT a custom loss/cost function I’m looking at. I understand what’s going on in the function, but I need to understand how the gradient output of the last network layer is calculated.
NOTE: My task it to implement this custom loss function into our bespoke C++ ML lib. But to do this, I need to “manually” calculate the gradients for the last layer of the network.
So, if I run my network:
results = my_network(inputs)
And then my loss function:
loss = my_loss_fn(inputs, results, targets)
loss.backward()
Finally, if I print out the grad_fn chain on “results”, I see:
grad_fn chain of "results":
SqueezeBackward1
DivBackward0
SliceBackward
SqueezeBackward1
Col2ImBackward
TransposeBackward0
MulBackward0
FftC2RBackward
ViewAsComplexBackward
TransposeBackward0
ViewBackward
LeakyReluBackward0   <=== This is the final layer of my_network
NativeBatchNormBackward
SlowConvTranspose2DBackward
So if I understand the autograd correctly, I would have to implement each of those grad_fn’s to arrive at the grad output for the LeakReluLayer?
EDIT: For the network, I'm just using a simple couple of layers. It's not meant to do anything:
class NetTest(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_chans, out_chans, kernel, stride, padding):
    super().__init__()

    #self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_chans, out_channels=out_chans, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride, padding=padding)
    self.trans = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=in_chans, out_channels=out_chans, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride, padding=padding, output_padding=0)
    self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=out_chans, eps=0,momentum=.1)
    self.leaky_relu = nn.LeakyReLU()

def forward(self, x):
    #x = self.conv(x)
    x = self.trans(x)
    x = self.batchnorm(x)
    x = self.leaky_relu(x)

    return x

The loss function looks like this (not sure where it came from):
def wsdr_fn(x_, y_pred_, y_true_, eps=1e-8):
    # x_ is the network input in STFT form
    # y_pred_ is the results of the network. It has been processed through istft already   
    # y_true_ is the target in STFT form
    y_true_ = torch.squeeze(y_true_, 1)
    y_true = torch.istft(y_true_, n_fft=N_FFT, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH, normalized=True)
    x_ = torch.squeeze(x_, 1)
    x = torch.istft(x_, n_fft=N_FFT, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH, normalized=True)
    y_pred = y_pred_.flatten(1)
    y_true = y_true.flatten(1)
    x = x.flatten(1)

    def sdr_fn(true, pred, eps=1e-8):
            num = torch.sum(true * pred, dim=1)
            den = torch.norm(true, p=2, dim=1) * torch.norm(pred, p=2, dim=1)
        return -(num / (den + eps))

    # true and estimated noise
    z_true = x - y_true
    z_pred = x - y_pred

    a1 = torch.sum(y_true**2, dim=1)   
    a = torch.sum(y_true**2, dim=1) / (torch.sum(y_true**2, dim=1) + torch.sum(z_true**2, dim=1) + eps)
    wSDR = a * sdr_fn(y_true, y_pred) + (1 - a) * sdr_fn(z_true, z_pred)

    return torch.mean(wSDR)


Can you clarify what you are trying to do? You say you want to calculate the gradient of the last layer of the network (leaky relu), but you also provide a loss function. The gradient calculation of the leaky relu layer is unrelated to the loss. Are you trying to calculate gradients of the model layer or the loss function?

First, it's quite non-standard to pass the inputs to the loss function, unless you have a custom loss that specifically requires them. This can happen, for example, when trying to make the distribution of the outputs follow (or conversely ignore) a distribution derived from the inputs, but it is not that common. Can you explain what your loss function does?
Secondly, regarding the gradient calculation, the last layer is usually the easiest one to calculate gradients for manually. It's straightforward to compute the partial derivative of the loss with respect to the final layer's parameters since it only involves differentiating two functions. So, no, you shouldn't have to re-implement everything. Could you share the graph of your model, or is it private ?
